# Civilization cards with toolmakers

Tags: stone-age

If, for any reason, the card remains unused till the end of the game, when scoring the toolmakers, do we take into account the value of "one-time" tools or just the permanent value of tools on our board?

Comment: You do not get to add the value of unused one-time bonuses. I'd post this as an answer if I had a more reliable source than just my experience playing this (both cardboard and digital).

Comment: Chaz, when I want to answer a questions I find most rules are available online somewhere.  Stone Age rules can be found at https://www.yucata.de/langnet/1/StoneAgeRules.pdf  if you want to cite the relevant bit.

Comment: The rules appear to not have a definitive statement about it; but Chaz is correct. Just can’t find a source at the moment either.

Comment: Im not very familiar with the game so dont want to answer the question myself.  But it seems that from the picture example scoring tools it just shows scoring for players tools and not the bonus ones on cards.  Also the cards.  in the explanation civ card it says ". He can add this tool once to a die roll"  this would infer thats the only thing it can be used for and can not be used for scoring.  But as I say its a game I've only played a few times years ago so dont feel confident enough to answer myself.  I think that lack of source in the rules is perhaps proof its not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the "one-use tool" cards do not count for scoring tool makers.

The rules specifically call out "Tool **tiles"** in the scoring section:

[image: scoring rules]

The "one-use tool" cards are exactly that: cards (i.e. not tiles). Nowhere in their description are "tiles" called out:

[image: tool card description]

Comment: I see. The english version calrifies it much better.